# How to mach number multiple of 0.05 with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

i searching a way to write a regular expression for validate numbers that are multiples of `0.05`

I need to validate number that have at least two decimal digit and if there is a second digit after the decimal point this digit need to be 5.

How can i modify this:

```
/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

Thanks for any type of help

Comment: `/^\d+(?:\.\d[05])?$/` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do it for you:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d)?[05]?$/
```

The nice thing about this regex is that it will also allow for rationals with only a tenths digit

```
var re = /^\d+(?:\.\d)?[05]?$/;

re.test(1.77)
=> false
re.test(1)
=> true
re.test(1.05)
=> true
re.test(1.07)
=> false
re.test(1.1)
=> true
re.test(1.10)
=> true
re.test(.5)
=> true
re.test(123.5)
=> true
```

Comment: Why did you put an optional on the [05] and not the other decimal point? I see how doing these would make it mathematically correct but I assumed he wanted the decimals to be there "I need to validate number that have at least two decimal"

Comment: @AfanfeFana glad to help, accept the answer if it's what you needed.

Comment: sorry for delay but on stackoverflow you have to wait some times before you can accept an answer..

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+\.\d[05]
```

That should work. This matches any digit, followed by any digit, followed by a 0 or 5

Comment: @nderscore Are you sure about that?

Comment: Don't you want \d+\.\d[05] to allow numbers like 123.45?